# Rubiks cube Old Pochman method

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am trying to get a successful blindsolve using the Old Pochman method.

I got my cubed scrambled, and I have no idea what to do with memorization when:

I need to shoot to a corner that has the buffer piece in it, but with the wrong orientation. How would you memorize this sequence? For letter memorization like

> J K M D V F H etc.

How would you memorize the letters so that it is successful?

(Trying better to explain it...) If I shot to a corner and the buffer piece was in it, the next step it to shoot the buffer piece to another location, but then that location has a different piece to what you memorized

Answer (score 1):

Use the letters to create sentences. 
To explain myself better i will use your example:J K M D V F H
You could memorize it like Jenny Keeps My Dear Van For Hours. Obviously if it has a real meaning it will be far more simple to memorize but this should work.
And about the actual solving you need to know 1 alg that is the 'y' perm and that if you do certain set-up moves you should be able to permutate all corners. Obviously it will take time but it is  For sure the way you do it